# How to properly use params.require in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've read [several](http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html) | [articles](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) about using `params.require(...)` in Rails, but nothing that shows them in a non-trivial, real-world scenario.

Specifically, the following URL will be called:

```
GET http://myapp.example.com/widgets/{clientUuid}
```

Where `{clientUuid}` will be a string. I just want to check (from the proper controller action) whether the provided `{clientUuid}` is non-null and non-empty. I'm wondering if I can just do this:

```
if params.require(params[:clientUuid]) == null
  response = { "error" => "bad client uuid" }
  render json: response, status: :bad_request
  return
end
```

And have non-nullness/non-emptiness enforced? If not, what can I do to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write:

```
if params[:clientUuid].blank?
  response = { "error" => "bad client uuid" }
  render json: response, status: :bad_request
  return
end
```

With `params.require` it is a bit more difficult, because `require` raises a `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception if the parameter is missing, but allows the parameter to return `false` (what I guess is still invalid in your example):

```
begin
  uuid = params.require(:cliendUuid)
rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing
  # nothing to do, just ensure the exceptions is rescued
end

unless uuid
  # handle missing uuid
end
```

Or:

```
begin
  uuid = params.require(:cliendUuid) || raise ActionController::ParameterMissing
rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing
  # handle missing uuid
end
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann (+1) - good to know about the `.blank?`. Sticking with the `params.require`, any chance you could update your code snippet to show how I could use `params.require` in a similar context (just curious!). Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my answer, but would not recommend to use the `params.require` version. IMHO `require` was build from your use case.

Answer (score 8):

You're overcomplicating a simple GET request by messing up the route and using a method thats meant for a completely different use.

The idea is that `.requires` should be used for non-idempotent request methods (`POST`, `PUT`,`PATCH`) where the request contains a body with parameters. It lets you take a single key from the params and whitelist the params contained - which matches the Rails ideom of nesting inputs in a hash with the name of the resource as the root key.

In that case using `.requires` lets you return a response code to the client that indicates that the request cannot be processed (422 - Unprocessable Entity) as the request body does not have the right structure.

While you could potentially use it creatively on a GET request its wrong from a restful application engineering standpoint. In your case you should be returning a `404 - Not found` response code if the `clientUuid` does not match a record. Usually in rails this is done by using `.find` which will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception which the framework catches.

Additionally if you have declared the route properly in the first place rails would actually give a 404 automatically as the request would not match if the id segment is missing.

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @widget = Widget.find(params[:clientUuid])
  end
end
```

If you want you could bail early so that the database is never queried if the param does not match a condition:

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if params[:clientUuid].blank?
    @widget = Widget.find(params[:clientUuid])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The article you posted re strong parameters is specifically about protecting your database data from user input, usually provided by forms.

```
params.require(:user).permit(:username)
```

The above code specifies that for the model User only allow the attribute username to be touched. If you try to update or create a user record in the user table with any other attribute e.g. email, you would get an error because the email attribute has not been 'permitted'. This is what is meant by whitelisting. You will only see the above code in `create` or `update` controller methods, or any other method that amends the data in some way. (An exception, of course, is deleting a record).

In your example, the parameter is provided as part of the url which you can also access via the rails provided `params` hash. However, as your method is not interacting with the db, you don't need to run it through the permit method.

[This resource](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) may help.